# K8s cluster in errors, nodes failing to start correctly

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

Brought up a k8s cluster with a single node and no autoscaling. Except networking (custom VPC and subnet) all other options are system default. The error received is this: All cluster resources were brought up, but: only 0 nodes out of 1 have registered; this is likely due to Nodes failing to start correctly; try re-creating the cluster or contact support if that doesn't work.

Have tried multiple options like choosing default networks, nodes with more than 1 node etc but nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you provide more details? Could you check if node is in `Ready` state `kubectl get nodes`. Please share `HPA` YAML, also output of `kubectl top nodes` and `kubectl describe nodes | grep "Non-terminated Pods:" -A 30`. What k8s version you are using.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I also apologize for the missing fact that the setup is in GKE. The issue is that GKE brings up the node but the respective cluster is unable to connect to the node.

k8s version is v1.15.9-gke.24
kubectl get nodes: No resources found in default namespace.
kubectl top nodes: Error from server (ServiceUnavailable): the server is currently unable to handle the request (get nodes.metrics.k8s.io)
kubectl describe nodes | grep "Non-terminated Pods:" -A 30: returns nothing

Comment: The cluster shows this status: All cluster resources were brought up, but: only 0 nodes out of 1 have registered; this is likely due to Nodes failing to start correctly; try re-creating the cluster or contact support if that doesn't work.

Comment: Did the same account who create this cluster changed node? Did you upgrade anything before this issue? Did you turn off some Google Cloude default services? Could check if you have in Google Compute Engine running VM from this cluster (If you run GKE cluster, all VMs are shown in Google Compute Engine). If yes could you check if you can find entries like `Supplied fingerprint does not match current metadata fingerprint.`

Answer (score 2):

Just adding this for visibility. I had a similar issue with this error when going through the UI or CLI. The issue did not appear when I tried in a different GCP project.

The issue was that the service account being assigned to the cluster was disabled. The service account is assigned when creating the cluster in `Node Pools > Security > Service Account`. Check in Service Accounts under IAM to see if that account is active. I was failing the health check portion due to the disabled service account. Once I enabled it and re-tried I no longer had any issues.